# Using vars package and the forecast function to plot future observations

Tags: r, statistics, forecasting

On the following site(https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/2) a Vector autoregressions is created.

```
library(vars)
VARselect(usconsumption, lag.max=8, type="const")$selection


var <- VAR(usconsumption, p=3, type="const")
serial.test(var, lags.pt=10, type="PT.asymptotic")


summary(var)
```

The code is rather simple, but when creating the forecast:

```
fcst <- forecast(var)
plot(fcst, xlab="Year")
```

The `forecast` function does not work. However, using the `predict` function does not yield the same plot as the forecast function.

Any suggestions, how to obtain the plot from the provided [link](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/2)?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean "the `forecast` function does not work"? I get exactly the plot you want and the predict function gives exactly the same forecasts:

```
> fcst <- forecast(var, h=3)
> pred <- predict(var, n.ahead=3)
> fcst
consumption 
        Point Forecast       Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
2011 Q1      0.7421472 -0.06576279 1.550057 -0.4934445 1.977739
2011 Q2      0.7980532 -0.03433474 1.630441 -0.4749743 2.071081
2011 Q3      0.7921921 -0.06526268 1.649647 -0.5191718 2.103556

income 
        Point Forecast      Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
2011 Q1      0.8208025 -0.2748906 1.916496 -0.8549154 2.496520
2011 Q2      0.7188650 -0.4437286 1.881459 -1.0591685 2.496898
2011 Q3      0.8241248 -0.3388670 1.987117 -0.9545177 2.602767
> pred
$consumption
          fcst      lower    upper       CI
[1,] 0.7421472 -0.4934445 1.977739 1.235592
[2,] 0.7980532 -0.4749743 2.071081 1.273028
[3,] 0.7921921 -0.5191718 2.103556 1.311364

$income
          fcst      lower    upper       CI
[1,] 0.8208025 -0.8549154 2.496520 1.675718
[2,] 0.7188650 -1.0591685 2.496898 1.778034
[3,] 0.8241248 -0.9545177 2.602767 1.778643
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! When running the R code above the dataset, `Error in as.matrix(y) : object 'usconsumption' not found`. Where do you get this dataset? I cannot reconstruct your example code ;(

Comment: Is `usconsumption` a `data.frame` or a `time-series object`?

Comment: Load the `fpp` package as instructed in the book you are citing.

Comment: Hi prof, if I want to extract the value of the point forecast of consumption in the above result like the value of 2011Q1, 2011Q2...? How can I apply the var forecast in training and testing set and then compute the prediction error like observed (from test set) - predicted value? I appreciate for the answers?

Comment: This is not the place to ask new questions.